# What happens if you give Miller Rucker's evidence?

Tags: deus-ex-mankind-divided

At the end of the mission where you're supposed to capture Rucker, assuming you got the evidence from his side room, you have the option of giving it to Miller or waiting and giving it to Vega.

I've browsed around the web and seen how it plays out if you give it to Vega, but I haven't see any word on what happens if you give it to Miller. I want to know what happens if you give it to him.

Answer (score 1):

Well I haven't been able to verify it yet since I crash when I use the train and so can't finish the game until they update it but from what I've read If you give it to miller he gives it to the big bad for no outcome, if you give it to vega you get access-codes from janus to a room you might need to access in the final mission depending on what route you want to take (there are two and you can do both if you hurry). If you keep it then don't give it to vega it will do nothing.

Comment: Nizze, If you read it somewhere, would you be able to look for and post the original link? It would greatly improve your answer!

Comment: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/142234-deus-ex-mankind-divided/74205274?jumpto=4

Post #6